# Не активны компоновщики в QT Designer

Tags: qt-designer

Подскажите, почему при создании main window по умолчанию не активны компоновщики?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

при этом в текстовом редакторе могу вручную задать необходимую компоновку и потом продолжить нормально работать в дизайнере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: сначала вы должны поместить в центральный виджет хотя бы один элемент, это же относится и к QGroupBox

Comment: @PavelGridin Да, действительно, спасибо большое!